# Javascript: My setTimeout function not working because of 3rd party

Tags: javascript, html

I have intergrated a third party code into my website, and suddenly the setTimeout and setInterval stopped working: Before the third party is loaded, everything works fine. setTimeout and setInterval that were scheduled to run after the third party is loaded, do not dun at all.
After removing the 3rd party code snippet they supplied, everything work.

My question is - how can it be? what can the third pary do that can stop my schedules?
I renamed any pointers to the returned value of the setTimeout function; I tried to play with the place where I put the snippet and / or the setTimeout code.
Nothing work.

It doesn't make any sense. and I don't know how to start debugging it.

Here is a simplified html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Demo</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
<!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
<!-- the alert pops up only when I remove the 3rd party snippet -->
    setTimeout(function(){      
        alert("done");
    }, 5000);   
</script>

<!-- This is the 3rd party code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $P; var prefix = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://'); var         _P = _P || [];
    _P.push(['setId', '123']);
    var PPP = document.createElement('script');
    PPP.type = 'text/javascript'; PPP.src = prefix +     'thethirdpartyIuse.com/functions.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var lastScriptTag = s[s.length - 1];
    lastScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(PPP, lastScriptTag);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help & guideness is appriciated!

Comment: I see no `$(document).ready({});` around any code...

Comment: Have you tried to change from alert() to console.log() ? Also have you tried to put the break point and debug through may be with firebug to check if the functions are being overwritten ?

Comment: Just a side note: A HTML comment inside the `<script>` is invalid. Use JS comments inside the `<script>` environment.

Comment: @Tomanow That is not needed in this case.

Comment: @Tomanow - Why do I need this? and anyway. I have it in the not simplified code.

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq I tried also log, same results. I tried to debug the code (also the 3rd party code), but I didn't see any "override". BTY, how does "override" of setTimeout looks like?

Comment: @Sirko - thx, in the original code there is no comments. But thx for point it up.

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? It works fine in liveweave: http://liveweave.com/OKMyjs
And indeed you should wrap your code in:

```
 window.onload = function() {

//your stuff

}
```

Comment: You know that `thethirdpartyIuse.com/functions.js` is just a cover up for the real thirdparty component right?

Comment: @A1rPun is right. I can't expose the real third party as it seems like a major bug of them, and we have business relationship with them.

Comment: and why do I need window.onload?

Comment: window.onload will wait for the window to be fully loaded and then execute your script. When you just write it down like this it will be executed when the browser gets to it. See also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180251/when-to-use-window-onload

Answer (score 0):

May be the external code redefines `alert` as something else. To see if this is the issue try changing your code to:

```
(function(myalert){
  setTimeout(function(){      
      myalert("done");
  }, 5000);
})(alert);
```

If this doesn't work the only reason I can think to is that the external script goes into an infinite loop. Functions registered with `setTimeout` will be executed once the Javascript event loop starts after the synchronous execution of `script` tags in the page and this may never happen if any toplevel stript hangs.

You should however see in this case the loading is taking forever (loading animation in the browser) and after long enough the browser should signal that there is a problem loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Something redefines your `alert` function.

Possible solutions:

- wrap your code in `(function(alert) { /* your code */ }(alert))`
- `Object.defineProperty(window, 'alert', { configurable: false, enumerable: true, value: alert, writable: false });` to protect your `alert` from redefining.
- do not rely on `alert` (in 99% of cases modal or `console.log` are superior solutions - `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm` are three functions blocking code execution in JavaScript).

Comment: The alert is just an example. even console.log doesn't work. The thing is that the setTimeout is overriden / canceled somehow by the third party, and I am trying to understand how.

Comment: You can block redefinition of setTimeout in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I found the probelm:
The 3rd party did `setTimeout(true)`for some reason (I assume by mistake).
In chrome, it cancel all schedules (`setTimeout` & `setInterva`).

I report the problem.