# How do you use increments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, slideshow

I am not sure how to use increments. 
through a function. i can't get the paragraph to show the array words

```js
<p id= "demo" 
var Array = ["hello", "goodbye"];
var mimg = document.getElementById(imageArray[0]);
mimg.setAttribute('src', [index]);
//var ArrayIndex = 0; 

function change() {
 ("src", Array[Index]);
 imageIndex++;
 if (Index >= Array.length) {
  Index = 0;
 }

}
```

Comment: You have to define imageIndex somewhere.... (outside of changeImage function)

Comment: how would you do that?   imageIndex=??

Comment: If you want to start from first array member, it should be 0, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to use your browser's console, [read this article *Using Your Browser to Diagnose JavaScript Errors*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors).

**Don't use setattribute function, use src attribute.**

```js
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4/"];

myImage.src = imageArray[0];

var imageIndex = 0; 

function changeImage() {
    myImage.src = imageArray[imageIndex];
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length)
        imageIndex = 0;
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        changeImage();
    }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<img id="mainImage" />
```

Comment: this helped my understanding on what i am doing but the image won't load, do you put the img id in the body?

Comment: `<script>
 var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

 var imageArray = ["images/1.png","images/2.png","images/3.png","images/4.png"];
myImage.src=imageArray[0];
var imageIndex = 0;

 function changeImage() {
  myImage.src(imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
 }

}
setInterval(function(){
changeImage();
},1000;)
</script>`

Comment: @sp000142 You need to call the function in onload event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180251/when-to-use-window-onload

Comment: image won't show `myImage.src = imageArray[0];` is seen as an error on the console

Comment: `myImage.src = imageArray[0];` shows error if :
1) you forget to add `<img id="mainImage" />` in your page.
or 2) you forget to set imageArray.

Comment: one image is a different size how would i make them all the same size?

Comment: set `image.height` or `image.width` like this : `image.width = 20px;` don't set the both, **just set one to respect the scale/format.**

Answer (score 0):

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = ["images/1.png","images/2.png","images/3.png","images/4.png"];
var mimg=document.getElementById(imageArray[0]);
mimg.setAttribute('src',photos[index]);
```

You aren't showing your relevant HTML, but I notice in this section you are getting an element with ID "images/1.png" and setting the src of that element to the value of something in photos[index].  You haven't shown how the photos array is loaded.  Do you actually have an element with an ID "images/1.png"?

In your function, you set the src of the mainImage to the values in imageArray rather than the values in the photo array.  That may be valid, but since that is different than what you did outside the function, I want to make sure that was intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about such solution:

```
var imageArr=["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", "images/4.png"];

$('#button'). on('click',function(){
var index=(Math.random(0,imageArr.length)*10)
$('#img').attr('src',imageArr[index])
});
```

Again you question is not clear, thus I think this will help you to get direction.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solution if you are using plain JavaScript

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage"),
    imageArray = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", "images/4.png"],
    imageArrayIndex = 0;

myImage.src = imageArray[imageArrayIndex++];

function changeImage () {
    myImage.src = imageArray[imageArrayIndex++];
    imageArrayIndex = imageArrayIndex >= imageArray.length ? 0 : imageArrayIndex;
}
```

Make sure that your element is defined as "img".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which sets a `data-index` attribute on the image to keep track of the selected index. This solution is compatible with down to IE8 and does not use the Jquery library. Run the code snippet below for a test (click the image to go to the next one).

```js
var mimg   = document.getElementById('main-image'),
    simg   = document.getElementById('sec-image')
    imgArr = [
      'http://placehold.it/50x50/00AAAA',
      'http://placehold.it/50x50/AAAA00',
      'http://placehold.it/50x50/AA00AA',
    ];
      
var loopImages = function(element, imgArray, startAt) {
   var index = element.getAttribute('data-index'),
       newIndex = 0;
      
   if (!index)
      newIndex = ((startAt && startAt < imgArr.length-1) || 0) + 1;
   else if (index < imgArr.length-1)
      newIndex = parseInt(index) + 1;
   
   element.setAttribute('data-index', newIndex);
   element.src = imgArr[newIndex];
};
      
mimg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    loopImages(e.target || e.srcElement, imgArr);
});
setInterval(function() {
  loopImages(simg, imgArr);
}, 500);
```

```html
<p>Preview (click to change)</p>
<img id="main-image" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/00AAAA">
<br>
<p>Preview with interval</p>
<img id="sec-image" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/00AAAA">
```

Comment: thank you for helping but could you add comments? because i am trying to understand code more and i don't understand everything in this code

Comment: @sp000142 It's pretty self-explanatory. If you don't understand functions like `addEventListener` or `parseInt`, or properties like `e.target`, please refer to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API).

Comment: This function is more advanced and flexible than the other answers because 1) it can be set on any element, 2) it can be used with any event/ function, 3) you can choose which image in the array to display first (eg, start at 2nd position) and 4) it doesn't pollute the window namespace with a global var.