# Call a function from another javascript program - functional programming

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, functional-programming

I have a program **isOvel.js** which has a function `isOvel(str)` and I want to use this function `isOvel(str)` in an another program **translate.js**. Am just started with Javascript functional programming, your help will be much appreciated.!! I could not find any duplicates, please post it if any.

Comment: Unless the scripts are included on the same page (isOvel.js first) and scoped globally, you can't do that as far as I know

Comment: is the function declared in global space?

Comment: That depends how you're running your Javascript (and has nothing to do with functional programming)

Comment: @Todd - No, I haven't declared in global space.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I did not understand the part - 'the scripts are included on the same page'. Am trying to test something with javascript, not developing any webpage.

Comment: @SLaks I am just running individual javascript programs, mainly to test functionality.

Comment: @chivas_hvn: **How**? Node.js? Rhino? HTML?

Comment: @SLaks Using **Node.js**

Comment: You're looking for `require()`.  See the documentation.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript file isn't "program" is "file" you can include several files on your page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <script src="isOvel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="translate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am trying to call and test `isOvel()` functionality from another js program, not building any webpage so please let me know how I can call it.

Comment: Did you see onload event ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180251/when-to-use-window-onload